# Why does an empty list in python give a length of 3?

Tags: list, python-3.x

When I type in

```
list = []

print(len(list))
```

it prints out `3`, not `0`.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I'm using python 3.3.

Comment: Not here it doesn't: http://ideone.com/cCg5mL.

Comment: Note that you also shouldn’t use the name `list` as that’s the name for the built-in type.

Comment: In addition to `list`, have you also shadowed the built-in `len` function?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way to get that result is the following way:

```
>>> len = lambda x : 3
>>> print(len(list))
3
```

To figure out what happened in your case, check what print, len and list are. This is what they *should* be:

```
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> len
<built-in function len>
>>> list
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

Note that you in your example do

```
>>> list = []
```

Which is not good practice as you now overwrite one of the built ins. That works, and it's allowed but it can be confusing.